# How to change the frequency in my auto arima function

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have a time series (tsibble object) and I need to apply the `auto.arima` function to find my model. The object is presented with a daily frequency along 7 years

```
# A tsibble: 2,557 x 2 [1D]
    bcUI Date      
   <dbl> <date>    
 1  13.6 2012-01-01
 2  36.0 2012-01-02
 3  33.7 2012-01-03
 4 200.  2012-01-04
 5 150.  2012-01-05
 6 230.  2012-01-06
 7  79.7 2012-01-07
 8  65.7 2012-01-08
 9  25.5 2012-01-09
10  35.7 2012-01-10
# ... with 2,547 more rows
```

When I appply the function

```
autoarima1<-auto.arima(bctsibble,trace = TRUE,approximation = FALSE,seasonal = TRUE)
```

the results come with a frequency of 7:

```
Best model: ARIMA(1,0,0)(2,0,0)[7] with non-zero mean
```

How can I change this frequency? The data is too big to share it all. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a `tsibble` object so you should use the fable package for automated ARIMA modelling. The `auto.arima()` function from the forecast package is designed for `ts` objects. Here is how to fit the model using fable:

```r
library(tsibble)
library(fable)

# Simulated data with same structure
df <- tsibble(
  bcUI = rnorm(2557, 120, 50),
  Date = seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), by="1 day", length = 2557),
  index= Date)

# Equivalent to auto.arima for a tsibble
fit <- df %>% model(ARIMA(bcUI))
```

Second, what do you want to change the period to and why? You have daily data, so it may have a weekly pattern (with period 7) and a yearly pattern (with period 365). Other seasonal periods for daily data are extremely rare. The `ARIMA()` function is automatically checking if there is significant period 7 seasonality. It won't look for period 365 seasonality as such longer periods are best handled in ways other than a seasonal ARIMA model.

See https://otexts.com/fpp3/complexseasonality.html#complexseasonality for a discussion of handling yearly and weekly seasonal periods in an ARIMA model.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply! I understand it, but I wanted to handle it as an annual seasonality not a weekly one. If I include the seasonal terms, applying a seasonal ARIMA model, could I get to a good result?

Comment: Read the link I provided. ARIMA models won't handle seasonal periods as large as 365.